# display spinner2 if item xy in spinner1 is selected not working correctly

Tags: android, spinner

i have two spinners.

If in the first one the Item "Diesel" is selected i want to display the second one.

```
sKraftstoffArt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
            if(sKraftstoffArt.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Diesel"){
                sPartikelfilterArt.setVisibility(sPartikelfilterArt.VISIBLE);
            }
        } 

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            return;
        } 
    });
```

I've implemented this code in the onCreate method. When i select a item during the runtime i'm not getting the selected item text... It works only if the activity gets created and the default value gets selected....

Where else do i have to implement it?

Regards,
float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your `sKraftstoffArt` object is not a final one, the check against it's selected item text inside an anonymous class won't work.

The `adapterView` among the parameters is your `ListView` instance to which you've assigned the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. 
The `view` parameter is the actual item (renderer) inside your `ListView` that has been clicked. This item is provided by your adapter's `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

Also, you should use the `equals` method of `String` to check whether two String values are equal.

So this won't work:

```
if(sKraftstoffArt.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Diesel")
```

Use insetad

```
if (adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Diesel"))
```

You might also want to add an `else` clause after this `if`, to hide the `sPartikelfilterArt` spinner when the selected item in the previous spinner is not "Diesel".

Please note, that every time you assign a new adapter to this list (which probably you don't, i still mention it just in case...), you should add the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to it again.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the selected item when i want to know the value by clicking a button? In that case i don't have a adapterView.

Comment: Ah i will just save the selected value in a seperate variable :-)